# I need to calculate dimensions of sperm cells from the following image? how can it be done?

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

1. This is the source image.
   [image: source image]
2. After grayscaling and applying median filter to reduce noice.
   [image: preprocessed]
3. Sobel edge detected image.
   [image: edges]
4. Binary of the grayscaled median filtered image.
   [image: binary]

dimensions to find are head length, head width, head area, head perimeter, tail length, overall area.

Am I on the right track? what should to be done now? I am stuck.

Comment: what do you mean by dimensions? Length of the head, length from head to end of tail? Or do you mean the "volume"?

Comment: Do you need to do this programmability? Is the scale (on all images) fixed? There is a [scale bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_scale) in the lower right of the image (the white line with 10um underneath).

Comment: Yes, Maljam. By dimensions, I mean head( width, length, area, perimeter), tail length , overall area.

Comment: Elliott Frisch..
I need to develop a system which takes a bunch of such images as input and outputs all the parameters (head width, head length, head area, head perimeter, tail length , overall area) in micrometer or pixels for each image. The scale on every image is fixed and identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Matlab but I would:

1. **segmentate/label the image (find and enumerate objects)**

   for example by flood fill.
2. **remove too small/big objects**

   that should leave just the sperms.
3. **find orientation and measure**

   You can use A* for this just start filling from any point that belongs to object. Then find the most distant point (maximal filled value) and you are either on end of tail or top of head. Now use A* from this point to obtain the other edge of object. The max filled value is the curve length of the whole sperm in pixels.
4. **Determine where is the head**

   You can isolate edge pixels (circumference) by selecting object pixels near empty space. Now separate the pixels into 2 groups (left right halves) with corresponding order. now you can easily compute thickness of any part of sperm and detect head (variable and or bigger thickness) and tail (constant small thickness). From this any measurement of dimension or area is trivial.

[image: img]